# Change url /help.php?page=somePage to /help/somePage with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have PHP code that shows me pages from folder:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$page = $_GET['page'];
if (file_exists('help-pages/'.$page.'.php')) {
  include('help-pages/'.$page.'.php');
} else {
  echo "not found";
}
?>
```

I need change ugly /help.php?page=somePage to /help/somePage. I read a lot about mod_rewrite, but it didn't help me.

PS. Sorry for my bad English :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done using mod_rewrite.  Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^help/(.+?)/?$ /help.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score -1):

I like using [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) just because its so simple to use when it comes to urls